# How to detect the path of a file with an executable .exe?

Tags: java, executable-jar, java-11

I packaged a .jar application to an .exe that runs under Java 11.
To run the executable, my application needs a parameters file that is in a `parameters.myapp` configuration.

I would like to associate this settings file with my application from any path (desktop, download, Images ....)
Is there a way in Java that my executable .exe recognizes the path automatically and can make `new File (__ folder__ + "parameters.myapp")`?

Comment: I would assume, your `.exe` at the back of everything would be having a `main` method somewhere. Just make sure from that point onwards, until the mandatory path followed by your app installation and start, in between you have this line of code that you state gets executed. This is what I could figure out from the details of the question at least.

Comment: I just added <cmdLine> </ cmdLine> in the configuration file and pass args [0] in the hand and it works! thank you nullpointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added   in the configuration file and pass args [0] in the hand and it works!